# View Pager showing the same Images on swipe

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap, android-viewpager

I have a relative layout which contains a viewpager to enable to me swipe images fetched from my web service.The fetched images are then stored in a ArrayList which contains a HashMap. I've logged the fetching part of from web service and the log indicates that I am indeed fetching different images. However, whenever I'm swiping from image to image, the viewpager displays the same image which is always the last image saved. I've logged the ArrayList of images in the Pager Adapter and it seems that I am getting the correct arraylist size but I'm getting the same bitmap in all sizes.

This is my PagerAdapter class:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> images;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> images) {
        this.context = context;
        this.images = images;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_image_video, null);
        RelativeLayout rlAttach = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rl_attach);
        ImageView imgAttach = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_attach);
        VideoView vvAttach = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.vv_attach);
        LinearLayout llOverlay = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_video_overlay);
        ProgressBar pBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pBar);
        LinearLayout llUnsupportFile = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_unsupport_file);

        Log.d(TAG, "image: " + images.size() + " " + images);
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) images.get(position).get("image");
        image = CommonUtilities.checkBitmapRotation(bmp);

        imgAttach.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vvAttach.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llUnsupportFile.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imgAttach.setImageBitmap(image);
        pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        setPreviewClick(imgAttach, position, rlAttach);

        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        return view == obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        View view = (View) object;
        container.removeView(view);
    }
}
```

This is where I set the adapter and set notifidydatasetchange:

```
  if (galleryList.size() > 0) {
                    llNoGallery.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    rlHasGallery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pbGallery.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    vpGallery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tvPageCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    mImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), galleryList);

                    for (HashMap getList : galleryList) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onMe: " + getList.toString());
                    }
                    vpGallery.setAdapter(mImageAdapter);
                    vpGallery.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);
                    vpGallery.setOffscreenPageLimit(galleryList.size());
                     mImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    tvPageCount.setText("1/" + galleryList.size());
                } else {
                    rlHasGallery.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    llNoGallery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
```

This is the function to save the images fetched to the arraylist:

```
private void saveImagesToArrayList(String photo) {
    bmp = null;

    if (!photo.isEmpty()) {
        bmp = imageLoader.loadImageSync(photo);

        // tmp hashmap for single image
        HashMap<String, Object> hmImage = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        hmImage.put("image", bmp);

        galleryList.add(hmImage);

        // tmp hashmap for single image
        HashMap<String, Object> hmImageInString = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        hmImageInString.put("image", photo);

        galleryListInString.add(hmImageInString);
    }


}
```

This is my ViewPagerChangeListener which shows the position of the image swipped to :

```
 ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        tvPageCount.setText(position + 1 + "/" + (galleryList.size()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
};
```

Here I have the setPreviewClick method to open up the image in full screen via intent. The images show here are correct here which displays different images on swipe.

```
  private void setPreviewClick(View view, int imagePosition, RelativeLayout rlAttach) {
    final int mPosition = imagePosition;

    rlAttach.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            intentViewActivity(mPosition);
        }
    });

    ImageView mImg = (ImageView) view;
    mImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            intentViewActivity(mPosition);
        }
    });

}
```

The intentViewActivity method is as follows:

```
 public void intentViewActivity(int position) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewImageViewPagerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("images", galleryListInString);
    intent.putExtra("image_position", position);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
}
```

The one of the parameter of the intentViewActivity method is the ViewImageViewPagerActivity which is this:

```
package com.epicamera.vms.i_neighbour.activity;



  public class ViewImageViewPagerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private String TAG = "ViewImageViewPagerActivity";

Toolbar toolbar;
private View temp_view;
private VideoView vv;
private TextView toolbar_title;
private ViewPager insideViewPager;
private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> imageList = new ArrayList<>();

Bitmap bmp = null;
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Get singleton instance
private String username, companyname, usertype, companylogo, userid, token, userphoto, usergender;
private String android_id;
private String regId;
private Bitmap attachment = null;
private int imagePosition = 0, actualPosition = 0;
private int onPageScrollPosition = 0;
private boolean isVideo = false;

private Handler fileCheckerHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable fileCheckerRunnable = null;

private Uri uri;

// AsyncTask
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> task;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_image_video_viewpager);
    CommonUtilities.toggleRotationAdvance(this);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_action_back);
    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    //remove the tittle
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


    SessionManager session = new SessionManager(this.getApplicationContext());
    // get user data from session
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    // session id
    username = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERNAME);
    // user id
    companyname = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_COMPANYNAME);
    // company id
    usertype = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERTYPE);
    // company id
    companylogo = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_COMPANYLOGO);
    // user id
    userid = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERID);
    // session token
    token = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_TOKEN);
    // session user photo
    userphoto = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERPHOTO);


    usergender = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERGENDER);

    android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    insideViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.inside_view_pager);

    imageList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("images");
    imagePosition = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("image_position");

    actualPosition = imagePosition;


    myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(ViewImageViewPagerActivity.this, imageList);
    insideViewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
    insideViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);
    insideViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(imageList.size());
    insideViewPager.setCurrentItem(actualPosition, false);
    myViewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    toolbar_title.setText(actualPosition + 1 + " / " + (imageList.size()));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

//        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.view_image_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.d(TAG, "id: " + item.getItemId());
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_savetogallery:

            String[] count = toolbar_title.getText().toString().split("/");
            int value = Integer.parseInt(count[0].trim()) - 1;
            HashMap<String, String> child = new HashMap<>();
            child.put("image", (String) imageList.get(value).get("image"));

            saveToGallery(child, "File");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

public void saveToGallery(HashMap<String, String> item, final String type) {
    //take the current position
    final String select_document_link = item.get("image");
    final String select_document_name = item.get("image");
    final String selected_document = select_document_name.substring(select_document_name.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, select_document_name.length());
    final String document_download_path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/i-Neighbour").getPath() + File.separator + selected_document;
    final File file = new File(document_download_path);

    Log.d(TAG, "path: " + document_download_path + " " + select_document_link);

    // Check is the file is exist
 //        if (file.exists()) {
//            //Open the file if exist
//            openFile(file);
//        } else {
    //Download and open the file, if does not exist
    try {
        Toast.makeText(ViewImageViewPagerActivity.this, "Downloading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                final ProgressDialog progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(this,
//                        this.getResources().getString(R.string.txt_title_downloading),
//                        this.getResources().getString(R.string.txt_document_downloading), true);
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //Download the document
                    final DownloadManager downloadManager;
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/i-Neighbour").mkdirs();


                    downloadManager = (DownloadManager) ViewImageViewPagerActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    // have to replace space to %20
                    String url = select_document_link.replace(" ", "%20");
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri)
                            .setTitle(selected_document)
                            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/i-Neighbour",
                                    selected_document)
                            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    downloadManager.enqueue(request);

                    //ADDED LOOP HERE UNTIL FILE DOWNLOAD IS COMPLETE
                    fileCheckerRunnable = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                            query.setFilterByStatus(DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED | DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED | DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL | DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING | DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING);
                            Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);
                            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                int status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
                                switch (status) {
                                    case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
                                        //download is waiting to retry or resume
                                        fileCheckerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                                        break;
                                    case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
                                        //download is waiting to start
                                        fileCheckerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                                        break;
                                    case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
                                        //download is currently running
                                        fileCheckerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                                        break;
                                    case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
                                        //download has successfully completed
                                        //Open the document
//                                                openFile(file);
                                        Toast.makeText(ViewImageViewPagerActivity.this, type + " saved to Gallery->i-
Neighbour", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 //                                                    progDailog.dismiss();

                                        //STOP REPEATING TASK
                                        fileCheckerHandler.removeCallbacks(fileCheckerRunnable);
                                        break;
                                    case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
                                        //download has failed (and will not be retried)
 //                                                    progDailog.dismiss();

                                        //STOP REPEATING TASK
                                        fileCheckerHandler.removeCallbacks(fileCheckerRunnable);
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    fileCheckerHandler.postDelayed(fileCheckerRunnable, 1000);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e);
                }
            }
        }.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "Error -> " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

//  outside viewpager change listener
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        toolbar_title.setText(position + 1 + " / " + (imageList.size()));

        onPageScrollPosition = position;
        Log.d(TAG, "onpagescrollposition: " + onPageScrollPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {


    }
};

/**
 * View pager adapter
 */
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> images;

    public MyViewPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> images) {
        this.context = context;
        this.images = images;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_image_video2, null);
        final VideoView vvFullScreen = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.vv_full_screen);
        final TouchImageView imgFullScreen = (TouchImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_full_screen);
        final ImageView imgVideoBg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_video_bg);
        final ProgressBar pBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pBar);
        final LinearLayout llVideoPlay = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_video_play);


        view.setTag("pos" + position);
        //Bitmap image = (Bitmap) images.get(position).get("image");
        String image_url = (String) images.get(position).get("image");

        imgFullScreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vvFullScreen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llVideoPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Glide.with(context).load(image_url)
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imgFullScreen);

        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        return view == obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        View view = (View) object;
        container.removeView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return super.getItemPosition(object);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where is the method setPreviewClick(1, 2, 3)?  I see you referencing it, but I don't see the method anywhere.

Comment: @Silmarilos I've added the methods on edit. Thanks =)